# SiteCollection Feature Upgrade Access Denied for Farm Admin

Tags: upgrade, feature-upgrade, solution-package, administration

My solution contains Site Collection scope features and has been deployed to Site Collections that the farm administrator has not been granted any explicit permissions.

If the farm administrator tries to visit the site collection in the browser he sees an Access Denied error message.

The farm admin now needs to deploy an upgrade to my Solution.

He has successfully called the powershell cmdlet `Update-SPSolution`

when the farm admin calls `SPContentDatabase.QueryFeatures("Site",$true)` it returns the feature that needs to be upgraded in the site that he has no permissions to access.

However if the farm admin calls `SPFeature.Upgrade($true)` then an access denied error is thrown.

How is the site collection feature upgrade supposed to work?

Should the farm admin delegate site collection feature upgrade to the site collection owner?

Should the farm admin try to impersonate the site collection administrator?

Is there some user I can elevate to that is guaranteed to be able to call Upgrade on a site collection feature?

Comment: I found this link. http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-GB/sharepointadmin/thread/936d5ad2-ec74-48e0-a3b4-f8fa1b9419d5 It suggests to "take ownership" of the site collection. But this doesn't feel right to me.

Comment: We found a way to elevate privileges enough that we can upgrade features in the site. I'm still not sure if we should elevate or delegate to the site collection admin. I'll leave it another week and see which answer gets the most votes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We found that by using PowerShell code like this

```
[Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity]::RunWithElevatedPrivileges( {
    $site = get-spsite "http://localhost/nonfarmadminsitecollection"
})
$elevatedSite = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite([Guid]$site.ID,$site.SystemAccount.UserToken)
```

We are then able to upgrade the features in $elevatedSite.

Comment: Note that RunWithElevated has no function within powershell. It's purpose is to revert the impersonated user back to the process identity. In a web application, this is the application pool identity. In Powershell, there is no impersonation.

Answer (score 3):

Farm Administrators do not by default have access to Site content.

Site collection feature upgrade and activation is normally delegated to the Site Collection Administrators (I think).

Comment: Is there some UI the Site Collection admin can use to upgrade the features?

Comment: Unsure, but have a look at Chris O'Brien's SPFeatureUpgrade Kit on Codeplex: http://spfeatureupgrade.codeplex.com/

Comment: I wish I could double plus up vote thanks for the link.

Comment: No worries :) Could mark as Answer so others may find an answer to similar question they have.